# Stop event communication from Other Nodes of Ignite cluster

Tags: java, spring-boot, ignite

We have several client nodes which are being allocated jobs/task from server nodes. Server nodes are responsible for work distribution among client code. After some time we want certain clients to go down. Before actually shutting them down we want clients to stop consuming all type of Ignite Events(Job events specifically). Is there any api which we can use or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

as described in documentation https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/events/listening-to-events#listening-to-events you just need to return false from event listener:

```
// Local listener that listens to local events.
IgnitePredicate<CacheEvent> localListener = evt -> {
    System.out.println("Received event [evt=" + evt + "]");

    // Implement your condition logic in stopListen(CacheEvent evt)
    return stopListen(evt);
};
```